# manipulate request string dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, request

i have a request link:

`<a href=index.jsp></>`

and i have some divs in another part of the page, which contain some values and change by the user or under certain conditions:

`<input id="var1" />`
`<input id="var2" />`

How can i update dynamically the url to have inside the value of these two vars, resulting in

`<a href=index.jsp?var1=1&var2=17></>`

Is there some easy javascript/jquery way, or, some html way perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var val1 = $('#var1').val(),
    val2 = $('#var2').val();


$('a').attr('href', function(i, src) {

    return src+ '?var1=' + val1 + '&var2=' + val2 ; 

});
```

Use the correct selector to select the element . Then set the `href` of the anchor , appending the querystring parameters to it.

If you want to change it in a particular event then you need to listen to the event and perform the same actions.

The same can be written this way which can be easier to understand.

```
 var val1 = $('#var1').val(),
     val2 = $('#var2').val();


    var src = $('a').attr('href');  // Get the current href

    var newSrc = src+ '?var1=' + val1 + '&var2=' + val2 ; 

    $('a').attr('href', src); // set the href
```

Comment: No; you need to escape the values.

Comment: @SLaks.. I don't thing escaping is necessary

Comment: @Sunhanth thanks for the reply, i will try it right away. can u explain me the `i` in `function(i, href)`? is it mandatory by convention or something?

Comment: `i` is nothing but the index.. The reason we are passing in 2 parameters is to access the `href` attribute... You can use any variable name you want .. Let me edit the post to make it more clear.. For more info check http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: @Sushanth--: Wrong.  What if one of the values has an `&` or `%`?  You **always** need to escape when concatenating into a structured string.

Comment: @Sushanth-- so can u suggest an improved version for that case?